# Attempt to generate ESRI REST Token generate 'no client_id specified' error even when client_id is in the request body

Tags: arcgis-online, rest, arcgis-rest-api

I'm making a HTTPS POST request to the following URL: http://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/oauth2/token/

In the Request body I've added the following JSON:

```
{"client_id":"<ID>","client_secret":"<Secret>","grant_type":"client_credentials","expiration":"1440","f":"json"}
```

Despite the client_id being clearly specified I always get the same response to my request:

```
{"error":{"code":400,"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"client_id not specified","message":"client_id not specified","details":[]}}
```

Is there something about the REST call I'm missing? Should I still be using JSON in the request body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm successfully using this method to obtain a token:

```
def get_token():
    # Retrieve a token from ArcGIS Online to enable access to private services
    token_params = {
        'client_id': "your_client_id",
        'client_secret': "your_client_secret",
        'grant_type': "client_credentials"
    }
    request = requests.get('https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/oauth2/token', params=token_params)
    response = request.json()
    token = response["access_token"]
    return token

agol_token = get_token()
```

Answer (score 3):

We use [python requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to make HTTPS post calls to arcgis online and to arcgis server. you can use urllib2, but we really like using requests. After you have that, these are the params we use to pass to the endpoint.

```
# some params to pass to the function below
username = 'your_arcgis_online_username'
password = 'your_arcgis_online_password'
url = 'https://www.arcgis.com'

def get_token(url, username, password):
    ''' use this to get a token from arcgis online '''
    gen_token_url = '{}/sharing/rest/generateToken'.format(url)
    # payload params for the post request
    params = {'username':username,
                  'password':password,
                  'client':'referer',
                  'referer':url,
                  'expiration':60,
                  'f':'json'}

    response = requests.post(gen_token_url, data=params, verify=False)
    data = response.json() # convert to json
    return data['token']
```